# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors general $n \times n$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the general $n \times n$ matrix which has $2$'s across the main diagonal, $-1$'s below and above the main diagonal?

Comment: work out for $2 \times 2$, $3 \times 3 $ matrix. Generalise

Comment: Do you mean all entries not on the diagonal are equal to $-1$, or just the ones beside the main diagonal entries?

Comment: I did work that out, their isnt a relationship?  That I can see anyways?  . Just the ones beside the diagonal are -1 the rest of the entries are 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by computing the characteristic polynomial of your matrix A, i.e. you need to compute the polynomial
$$ p(x) = \det(x\mathbb{1} - A) $$
where $\mathbb{1}$ is the identity matrix, and then solve $p(x) = 0$. The roots will be your eigenvalues, and once you have them you can easily find the eigenvectors.

If I'm not wrong the characteristic polynomial in the case $n\times n$ turns out to be given by
$$ (x-2)[(x-2)^{n-1}-n+1] $$